# Paypal: Pending payments with Express Checkout

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I have implemented Paypal Express Checkout on my website. So far everything seems to work in my sandbox, except that the payments are not processed. Every payment is "pending".

The only reason I get is

```
    RECEIVING_PREFERENCE_MANDATES_MANUAL_ACTION
```

in the API response after executing the payment via API.

I cannot find any documentation on the reason, does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Are you working in the sandbox or live?  Are you using currency codes in the payment that don't match your account, by chance?  Something about the payment is triggering a rule in your account where you've set that you want to approve such a payment before letting it go through.  This could be fraud filters or general settings in the PayPal profile.

Answer (score 18):

You have probably already solved the problem, but maybe someone else has similar problem.

I believe the reason for this is because the payments are in a currency that you do not hold, you need to configure your Payment Receiving Preferences in your PayPal account. Otherwise, your payment status might be pending until you manually approve the payment in your PayPal account.

1. Log in to your PayPal business account at www.paypal.com. Click the profile icon (Profile menu) on the top right side of the page. From the Business Profile menu, select Profile and Settings. (Note: If you do not see the profile icon on the top right, select Profile which appears in the top menu when the My Account tab is selected.)
2. From the left menu, click **My selling tools**.
3. In/under the **Getting paid and managing my risk** section, click the Update link for the **Block Payments item**.
4. Update **Allow payments sent to me in a currency I do not hold** to "Yes, accept and convert them to U.S. Dollars") and click Save.

Comment: For me: 1. Click *Settings* icon (top right corner). 2. On the left, select menu item *My selling preferences*. 3. Find option *Block payments* and click *Update*... Maybe they changed the menu structure slightly.

Comment: "I believe the reason for this is because the payments are in a currency that you do not hold" - no. I read this constantly, it's not the case